# Price value not being passed using an interface Java Observer Pattern

Tags: java, junit, observer-pattern

On my course I am learning the different development patterns and the problem i am stuck with is an implementation of the Observer Pattern [1]: http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html, and them problem i am having is passing a value from the subject, that has been set using a JUnit test, to the observer to it can buy/sell a number of shares. My main question is: What's the problem i am not seeing? and a secondary question: Would my buying/selling of shares code work? if doesn't work, please don't post a solution to the 2nd as i would like to fix atleast one bit myself.

Interface:

```
public interface ShareWatcher {
public void updatePrice(double price);}
```

Subject:

```
 public class Share{
    public double price = 1.00;

    ArrayList<ShareWatcher> list = new ArrayList<ShareWatcher>();

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public boolean addShareWatcher(StockBroker stockBroker) {
        boolean result;

        if(!list.contains(stockBroker)){
            list.add(stockBroker);
            result = true;
            }else{
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean removeShareWatcher(StockBroker stockBroker) {
            boolean result;
        if(list.contains(stockBroker)){
           list.remove(stockBroker);
           result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Observer:

```
    public class StockBroker implements  ShareWatcher{
    Share share = new Share();
    public int portfolio ;

    double price;
    double buy, sell;
    public int increment;

    public StockBroker(double SB_BUY, double SB_SELL, int SB_INCREMENT) {
             this.buy = SB_BUY;
      this.sell = SB_SELL;
      this.increment = SB_INCREMENT;
      System.out.println(buy + "" + sell + "" + increment);
    }

        @Override
    public void updatePrice(double price) {
        this.price = share.getPrice();
    }

    public int getPortfolio() {

     while (price > 2 && price < 2){
            if(price < buy){
    portfolio = portfolio + increment;
              System.out.println("SB2 " + portfolio);
            }else if(price > sell){
                portfolio = portfolio - increment;
            }
        }
        return portfolio;
        }

}
```

and not sure if this would be needed on here, if not feel free to edit out, but the JUnit Test:

```
public void testChangePrice1() {
        final Share share = new Share();
       final StockBroker stockBroker = new StockBroker(SB_BUY, SB_SELL, SB_INCREMENT);
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(stockBroker));
        share.setPrice(PRICE5);
        final int expectedValue2 = 500;
        assertEquals(expectedValue2, stockBroker.getPortfolio());
    }
```

Comment: This condition stands out as problematic: while (price > 2 && price < 2)

Comment: @alexroussos ah thanks, forgot that bit of legacy code was there as it was from a copy paste job from another class i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems that you are not understanding that the observer pattern is basically about a CALLBACK after a certain event.

Meaning: the observers can register themselves somewhere; in your terms, they would be using the addShareWatcher() method of Subject.

Then, when for some reason the price is changed, Subject should iterate its list of ShareWatchers ... and invoke "updatePrice()" on each of the objects.

Side note: of course this is just example code; but keep in mind that you should not use ordinary "double" values that represent currency (see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13 on alternatives).

Comment: Ah thanks didn't realise i had to iterate through the list to call updatePrice(), probably what i get for working on 4 different programs at once instead of focusing on a single one. And i'll check out the currency link as you got me curious about why not to use the double type for it.